# I wish it be Vs. I wish it would be

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, modal-verbs

> I wish it **be** Christmas every day.
>
> I wish it **would be** Christmas every day.

What is the subtle difference here? Does the first sentence imply that the speaker's wish is more strong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first one isn't grammatical - if anything it should be "I wish it *were*" IMO.

Comment: In the context of *wishing* something for the present, I'm afraid **none** is correct. So, I wish it **was** Christmas everyday.

Comment: @MaulikV Whoa?! Are we considering correct use of the subjunctive to be incorrect these days? "I wish it **were** Christmas" is subjunctive, although common usage has made it virtually archaic, these days. The simple present subjunctive form of the being verb is "be" (contrast with "is" for the indicative mood). So if you want to be super crazy purist, you should sound like a pirate and say "If this **be** correct grammar, I just don't know any more." Ref.: http://www.wordpower.ws/grammar/gramch09.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I wish it be Christmas everyday.

Your first example isn't common usage and isn't grammatical in most settings.

"be" here as a *bare infinitive* is wrong; it should be conjugated. You have a few options. All of the options are past tense, and only vary based on their *[grammatical mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood)*

**[Subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood#Subjunctive):**
 <sub>This is probably the one I would go for in most situations.</sub>

> I wish it **were** Christmas every day.

"The subjunctive mood is used to express a wish or possible situation that is currently not true."
<sub><sub>[[Source]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)</sub></sub>

**[Indicative Mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood#Indicative):**

> I wish it **was** Christmas every day.

This is probably quite common among most native speakers. However it's *technically* incorrect, this is discussed in more detail in [this question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)

**[Conditional Mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood#Conditional):**

> I wish it **would** be Christmas every day.

This is what you have used in your second example. However, I'd consider substituting "would" for "could".

> I wish it **could** be Christmas every day.

---

> As an aside, there's also a difference between everyday and every day. – [TRiG](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/191/trig)

"**everyday**" means commonplace, plain, unremarkable

> Breathing and eating are just some of my everyday requirements.
> The groom got some funny looks for turning up to his wedding in everyday clothes.

"**every day**" means that something happens... well... every day.

> I like to go swimming every day.
> Every day except Sunday the post is delivered at 8am.

Comment: Neat answer but as far as I know there cannot be indicative mood for unreal situations.

Comment: Yeah, my original edit **indicated** (pun, lol) that it was technically incorrect. I've edited that back in.

Comment: Most uses of *would* after *wish* are actually the by-your-leave sort: *“I wish my parents would let me stay up late on weekends.”*  That is not a conditional use, but a volitional one. It means he wishes his folks **were willing** to let him stay up.

Comment: As an aside, there's also a difference between *everyday* and *every day*.

Comment: @Trig, I wouldn't have noticed that distinction! I was just reading it as "every day"

Comment: @TRiG - You should tell Wizzard that!

Comment: @Mrt The subjunctive mood is dying out of English. The present subjunctive ('if [noun] *be* [complement]') is so rare in modern English that most native speakers will flag it as an error. The past subjunctive ('if [noun] *were* [complement]') has not been eroded that far, but native speakers do not generally recognize a difference in meaning from the indicative, 'if [noun] *was* [complement]', and will only write *were* if they are trying to be scrupulously correct. Both forms will probably be gone altogether in a century or two.

Comment: @Mrt (And since I brought up AAVE in my answer, AAVE does use 'X be Y', but *not* as the subjunctive; it signifies [habitual aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_be), instead.)

Comment: You can also use a non-bare infinitive: "I wish it **to** be Christmas every day."  That would be perceived as... weird, but as a native speaker I'm not good enough at the grammar to figure out exactly why it's weird.  But I'm fairly certain it's grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you heard the contraction "it'd" for "it would", making both sentences equal?

Answer (score 0):

In "Standard" English, "I wish it be Christmas every day" is considered ill-formed. It *might* be well-formed in [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English), which has a distinctly different set of rules for *be*, but I do not know for sure, and I can't tell you for sure what it would mean in that dialect if it were acceptable.

Your other option, "I wish it would be Christmas every day", is acceptable in Standard English, but "I wish it was Christmas every day" is more idiomatic.  Native speakers will not register a difference of meaning between these two options.

(Regardless, what a horrible thing to want.  They would never stop playing all that saccharine music on the radio!)